# ls command does not work in VxWorks target prompt

Tags: ftp, target, ls, vxworks, cd

I am new to vxworks and getting the problem after loading the VxWorks image from host machine to target machine. After loading the image at target machine(including build in symbol table), I am getting issue in commands cd, ls etc. cd command is getting success but while executing ls command after the cd it shows error as value = -1 = 0xffffffff(print error code as 0x3d0004). I am not able to resolve the issue after a lot of tried in building the VxWorks images. Request anyone to please help in this regard. I am also not sure whether the cd command is executed successfully or not since I am not able to see any FTP message on the network while executing the CD or LS command.

Thanks
Vaibhav

Answer (score 5):

Propably the initial directory is not set. Try changing to one of the drives of your machine (e.g. `cd "/tffs0"`) before using `ls` or commands like that.

To obtain a list of all available devices type `devs`.